# Ember 2 - Loading Nested Route in parent route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

I have two routes:

- `/users/:user_id`  (aka `user`)
- `/users/:user_id/roles`  (aka `user roles`)

I now want to show the `user roles` within the `user` route.
I still want to have a separate `user roles` route.

When `user roles` are being loaded within the `user` route, the page should show the `user roles` section/template as `loading` (Because of requests to the server for `user_roles` should continue to be separate, I don't want to load `user_roles (ajax)` from within the `user` route because it will slow down the route loading).

How do I achieve this?

- I think I can make an asynchronous component called... `user-roles-component`, and feed `user` into it like so: `{{user-roles-component user=user}}`. Then I can use this component on both of my routes. Except that in case of `user roles` route, I won't be loading model?. And I will not be violating DDAU since I will be dealing with `user_roles` data directly in my component.
- Or I just make a service called `user-roles-service` that deals with asynchronous loading of `user_roles` given the `user` and also pass it in both routes and render using a custom component that will be in both of the routes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a [loading state](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_code-loading-code-substates) within your route and load the content of roles once you click in one button/link and pass that received content to your component.

An alternative is to create a loading state in your component as well (and probably the way I'd do). To do that you would receive an `Promise` from your ajax request (there are several ways to do that: `.find()`, `.query()`, `ember-ajax`, `ember-network`). You would activate the loading state of your component once you click the button/link to load the content, and once the promise is resolved you change the state of your component again.

Both ways your component can show its content once it receives the data and you preserve AUDD (Actions Up, Data Down).